# Go to definition not working in VS Code version 1.47.2

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code with Angular 8 and TypeScript 3.9.6 and suddenly when I'm on a template, ctrl+click or F12 to go to definition doesn't work any more. I got the following pop up message:

[image: screenshot of error message]]

I tried to uninstall and reinstall but was not able to solve the issue.
These are actually installed extensions:

```
Angular.ng-template
Anjali.clipboard-history
byi8220.indented-block-highlighting
CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2 
cyrilletuzi.angular-schematics     
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
eamodio.gitlens
EditorConfig.EditorConfig
eg2.vscode-npm-script
esbenp.prettier-vscode
FallenMax.mithril-emmet
infinity1207.angular2-switcher
johnpapa.angular-essentials
johnpapa.Angular2
johnpapa.vscode-peacock
johnpapa.winteriscoming
ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome
msjsdiag.debugger-for-edge
nick-rudenko.back-n-forth
nrwl.angular-console
PKief.material-icon-theme
```

Answer (score 20):

I found in July 2020 that downgrading the vs-code 'angular language service' to version 0.1000.3 fixes the "Go to definition" functionality.
Here is an image showing where to downgrade:
[image: How to downgrade]

Comment: I'm using version 0.901.11 of angular language service ( june 10 2021 ). With angular 11.