# VScode abnormal context menu

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem with context menu (right-click menu) in VScode. After installing couple of extensions (at the moment I can't even say which exactly, I remember GitLens and I think this one breaks my IDE) my context menu changed and I have no longer Go to definition and other useful stuff there. I tried to reset settings by editing settings.json file but there was nothing unusual there. Also I tried reinstall VScode completely, removing also folders:

C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code

C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming\Code

but it didn't help. I went through google and stackoverflow but none of solutions works or seems to be suitable to my case (one of suggestion was lack of memory, but I have like 64G so it shouldn't be a problem). I found one reddit thread describing my issue, but there was no remedy there. Can you please help me?

[my context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOnMO.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: possibly reported bug https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/113175 which has workarounds including reducing the number of extensions that elongate the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

The following looks similar to your issue.

[Go to definition not working in VS Code version 1.47.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950553/go-to-definition-not-working-in-vs-code-version-1-47-2)

Otherwise:

If you have many extensions I suggest noting down all the extensions you have.

Do a process of elimination, remove each extension until you get the menu item back.

If you have too many extensions then eliminate half.

```
-> Has the problem disappeared?
   -> Yes. Then one of the extensions removed is the culprit.
   -> No. Then your problem extension is still there. 
      -> remove another half and keep removing until the issue is resolved.
```